# PostgreSQL - What is the best database model for a product and multiple types of ratings of that product?

Tags: database, postgresql, data-modeling

I have a table named `products`. I want now to implement different types of rating (grades from 1-10) for a product, for example grade for robustness, price/quality etc. Later on I want to query the table products and filter by these ratings. What would be the best data model here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table called `RatingTypes` if you want to manage this list, or an enum in your application code called `RatingType` if you want it to be hard coded, for example if you have business logic which depends on the rating type. Then create a table called `ProductRatings` which (in addition to `Value` obviously) has the columns `ProductId` and `RatingTypeId` (this is either a foreign key to the `RatingTypes` table or just an integer to represent the `RatingType` enum) which gets a row for each product and rating type.